# How to write a simple wrapper over an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am writing a class to make stl map thread safe. Since we only use a limited set of features of the stl map, the class is implemented as follows:

```
template<typename key, typename val>
class ts_map {
private:
    std::map<key, val> hash_map;
    std::mutex mtx;

public:
    void insert(const key &k, const val &v);
    val& operator[](const key &k);
};

template<typename key, typename val>
void ts_map<key, val>::insert(const key &k, const val &v)
{
    mtx.lock();
    hash_map.insert(std::make_pair(k, v));
    mtx.unlock();
}

Template<typename key, typename val>
val& ts_map<key, val>::operator[](const key &k)
{
    val ret;
    mtx.lock();
    assert(hash_map.find(k) != hash_map.end());
    ret = hash_map[k];
    mtx.unlock();

    return ret;
}
```

Since the key might not be in the map, we want to implement 
find(const key &k) and end() methods in our thread safe map to find if a key exists or not.

```
if (my_map.find(key) == my_map.end()) {
     // do something
 } else {
      auto &v = my_map[key];
 }
```

What is the simplest way to implement a wrapper over the iterator of a container?

Comment: Your operator[] is never going to be thread safe, the lock is released and you are holding a reference. Another thread may modify the same entry.

Comment: You can only be partially "thread safe" using this technique. And, depending on your thread-safety needs this method can turn out to be rather inefficient. Though you can make individual operations thread safe, you can't perform multiple operations without introducing more synchronization, which is doubly inefficient compared to synchronizing at a higher level to begin with. Also, some careful uses of containers allows them to be used across threads without them needing a mutex.

Comment: @dgsomerton You are right. However the lock is protecting the stl map's internal data structures. If the value has to be modified a lock will be taken which is going to be specific to the val object.

Comment: There is undefined behavior if `std::mutex` destructor is called with the mutex owned. Better use a wrapper like `std::unique_lock`.

Comment: @0xhacker It would be better to return a const reference if it is not being modified, and make the method const. But how long will that reference be valid ? Will another thread re-oreder the container.

Comment: @dgsomerton Yes, another thread might do an insert in which case the container can be re-ordered while holding a reference to the value object. Is that a problem? As I said earlier the threads are protecting the map itself and not the objects in the map. Also you can assume that objects are not deleted from the map.

Comment: @0xhacker would it not be possible for the re-ordering to cause objects to be copied and deleted within the container, making the reference held outside the container invalid. That would be my concern with this model. There is a similar construct in some legacy code I maintain.

Comment: @dgsomerton yes. that is possible. C++ likes creating copies :) . So, what constructs should be used to solve such problems?

Comment: @0xhacker why do we need a mutable reference ? will a copy do ? can we modify a copy and then atomically update the container ? Is the object too large to copy ? Create an atomic operation on the container. Can the lock be held while the container is iterated, make iterators that lock. I would make atomic methods that handled the operation I wanted to be thread safe.